# Mysql adding slave to a master->master

Tags: mysql, replication

I have an existing MySQL database as `master1 <-> master2 -> slave` and I want to add another slave off master2. If I issue the `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;` on master2 necessary to dump the db, will this in any way affect master1? And how does it affect master2 before the dump is complete and the `UNLOCK TABLES;` is issued?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following for non-GTID replication:

1. Stop replication to the current Replica off Primary2.
2. Copy the MySQL tree to the new Replica.
3. Copy `my.cnf` also, but change `server_id` (all servers must have distinct numbers).
4. Restart both Replicas; both will catch up soon.

(I have not tried it for GTID-based replication.)

Copying the disk is faster than most other techniques.

Rather than Primary-Primary, consider Galera or InnoDB Clustering.

Answer (score 0):

No, locks on the instance master2 will not affect queries on master1.

However, you should also consider solutions that don't create locks.

You can use `mysqldump --single-transaction` to acquire a consistent export of data without locking, provided your tables are InnoDB (which they should be).

I can also recommend Percona XtraBackup as a professional database backup tool for MySQL. We used this at my last job to create replicas every day. It was much faster and did not lock the source as it created a backup.

Using the backup to initialize a replica is much faster, because it doesn't need to run an import like a mysqldump backup does. You might like to read the guide here: https://docs.percona.com/percona-xtrabackup/8.0/set-up-replication.html